# Creating android toolbar with material metrics

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'd like to create a toolbar in my app that seems like the one in the gmail application. There is a description about material toolbar metrics here: https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar

This says that there should be a 16dp space to the left of the navigation icon and a 72dp one before the title, could you please help me to make this work?

[image]

Currently it looks like this:
[image]

Toolbar xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/material_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_bg"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

In my styles.xml:

```
<style name="DefaultTheme.Toolbar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I don't think that's true, but in any case, I have an existing application to transform, not creating one from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Use Like This:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
```

Set your Title with using

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

Guideline says:

Icon: 24dp

Touch target on both: 48dp

Your Menu Items will have 48dpx48dp dimensions by default. So your icon size must be 24 dp. (For xxhdpi 72 px etc.)

Just that simple. You do not have to do anything more. By using these, my app passed through Featured App Review.

If you want to add left padding to your Title, you can do like that:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetLeft="72dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="72dp">
```

It should make 72dp.

Comment: Thanks a lot for yout answer, I'm trying to solve this for quite some time! I'm currently doing it this way actually, but the dimensions are not as expected, I wonder what I'm missing... So do I need to define custom (24dp) icons for this to happen in my drawable folder? Should I extend the touch target somehow? Can it be a problem that my main style is extended from Theme.AppCompat.Light? Please see my updated questions with the current dimensions and xmls.

Comment: @Analizer if you haven't changed standard ActionBarDrawerToggle there is no problem. My toolbar was just like yours. It's fine.

Comment: I think that too, but sadly this does not met the requeirements. It can't be that this code is messing stuff up, right?
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(activity, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {...}
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {...}};
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

Comment: @Analizer it looks like doesn't match the requirements but it actually does. Guys, who reviewed my app said okay to this. Because Standard Toolbar comes likes this, it does not match their own guideline. Also you can add inset padding. I will update my answer now.

Comment: Thanks a lot @oguzhand, it's finally working! Bounty well spent :)